# Что написать в переменной var

Tags: pascal, массивы

Даны массивы A(N) и B(N). Образовать новый массив C(N) путём попарного умножения элементов массивов A и B. В массиве C(N) определить число нулевых элементов.
Само решение

```
K:=0;
For i:=1 to n do
Begin
C[i]:=a[i]*b[i];
If c[i]=0 then inc(k);
End;
```

Comment: Хм. Кто-то сделал за вас д/з, а шапку-то и не написал? А учить язык вы считаете ниже своего достоинства?

Answer (score 1):

```
var
  A, B, C: array[1..n] of Integer;
  i, k: Integer;
```

Comment: var
  A, B, C: array[1..n] of Integer;
  i, k: Integer;
K:=0;
For i:=1 to n do
Begin
C[i]:=a[i]*b[i];
If c[i]=0 then inc(k);
End;

Ошибка не известный идентификатор n 
Ошибка повторно обьявлен индефикатор  K

Comment: У вас в коде не видно где объявлено k. Что такое n, откуда оно берётся?

Comment: @Дож: не стоит разжёвывать человеку, который не знает даже как объявлять переменные. Пусть или выучит, или получит свою честную двойку. Помогайте лучше тем, кто этого достоин.

Comment: Я сам для себя решу что кому разжёвывать, спасибо.